# inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation notepad++ Python

Tags: python, indentation

I am getting an inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation error after adding only one line of code and I can't see why it would throw the error, here is the code:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret) #create authentcation handler

auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret) #set access tokens to connect to twitter dev account

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True) #consume tweepy api function, 

tweets = api.user_timeline('realDonaldTrump', count=30) 

tweets_list = []
for each_tweet in tweets:
    tweets_list.append(each_tweet._json)
with open('tweets.csv', 'a') as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(tweets_list, indent=4))

my_demo_list = []
with open('tweets.csv', encoding='utf-8') as csvFile:  
    all_data = json.load(csvFile)
    for json_tweet_data in all_data:
        tweet_id = json_tweet_data['id']
        text = json_tweet_data['text']
        favorite_count = json_tweet_data['favorite_count']
        retweet_count = json_tweet_data['retweet_count']
        created_at = json_tweet_data['created_at']
        #lang= json_tweet_data['lang']
        my_demo_list.append({'tweet_id': str(tweet_id),
                             'text': str(text),
                             'favorite_count': int(favorite_count),
                             'retweet_count': int(retweet_count),
                             'created_at': created_at,
                             'lang':str(lang)
                            })
        print(my_demo_list)
        tweet_json = pd.DataFrame(my_demo_list, columns = 
                                  ['tweet_id', 'text', 
                                   'favorite_count', 'retweet_count', 
                                   'created_at','language'])        
print(tweet_json)
```

the #lang = json_tweet_data['lang'] line is where the error is appearing and if I remove it or comment it out like it is in the code shown, it will work fine, from what I can see everything is indented fine, what could be the issue here?

Comment: It is inconsistent, look at the line below `with open('tweets.csv', 'a') as file:`...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It means exactly what it sounds like: you indented your code with spaces in some places and with tabs in others. To fix this, in Notepad++, go to **Edit** -> **Blank Operations** -> **TAB to Space** (PEP 8 recommends using spaces vs. tabs).

Answer (score 0):

To be sure about spacing in Python scripts, you can use some of sophisticated text editors. I would recommend you to use Sublime Text 3 or Atom so you can easily handle it next time.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, i will look into those editors then

Comment: I've always preferred Visual Studio (free IDE for personal/educational/open-source use) or Visual Studio Code (free text editor for all uses). VS Code is built off of the same framework as Atom and is similar in many aspects, but is faster. And Sublime costs money... Anyway, this is strongly opinion-based, but I thought I'd throw in my two cents.

Comment: This program is notorious for displaying an annoying pop up each time you open it. Avoid! https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/solved-disable-update-available-pop-up/1381/42